# Optimization solution / algorithm for occupying tenants in houses (combinations)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, linear-programming

I need to solve an optimization problem in which tenants have to occupy houses according to preferred location and neighbors.

Here's the inputs:

n houses: h1,h2,...,hn, 
m tenants: t1,t2,...,tm

selections:
Each tenant has to select up to 3 locations according to priority 1-first priority, 2-second priority, 3-third priority.
Each tenant has to select up to 3 neighbors according to priority 1-first priority, 2-second priority, 3-third priority (can be also who NOT to live next to...)

For example: 
t1 wants to live in houses:
highest priority (1): h12 
mid priority     (2): h5 
lowest priority  (3): h3

t1 wants the following to be his neighbours:
highest priority (1): t5
mid priority     (2): t15 
lowest priority  (3): t6

- a weighting factor can be considered (not compulsory) as for the balance between required location and neighbours, for example, 0 location and 1 neighbours for a tenant who wants his friends closed to him but doesn't care where his house will be located, or 1 location and 0 neighbours for tenant who wants high priority location and doesn't care who his neighbours are (0.5 location and 0.5 neighbours for a tenant who wants the algo to equally balance his selections)

I'm looking for an optimization algorithm to provide the optimal solution (if exists) for occupying the tenants in required houses according to inputs.
What type of problem is this? Optimization? What is the best way to solve this type of problem? linear programming? 
Note: inputs can be changes to simplify the solution or in order to allow to algo to converge more reliably.

How do I mathematically formulate:
(1) House location proximity relationships for representing the houses (spanning tree?), how do I represent houses that are close or far away? 
(2) Neighbouring relationships (tenant wants to live next to X but not next to Y) with priorities? 
How do I write these conditions / constrains as equations?

I need a good starting point, academic papers, ideas, documents, how to tackle this problem.

Help is MUCH appreciated!

I can use Matlab, Python or any coding language / platform to test ideas.

Comment: I have used Mixed Integer Programming models for problems that resemble this.

Comment: It is not exactly a match for your question, but you may find approaches and objective function for the [stable roommates problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed an optimization problem as long as you have exactly one fitness function you want to maximize.

If your problem had only priorities of type "I want this house". It would be an assignement problem. You could solve it with an Hungarian (also called Kuhn-Munkres) algorithm.

The idea is to build a dual graph with houses on one side and tenants on the other. You put edges between every pair house/tenant with weights according to priorities (i.e. 1 if want this house else 0). You also have to create sink nodes on the side with the less node because this algorithm will allocate exactly one house to each tenant maximizing weights selected. For instance if n>m, create n-m ghost tenants (with all edges at weight 0) to match the left empty houses. 
This algorithm is of complexity O(N^3) with N = max(n, m).

The priorities of type "I like this neighboor" are quite more complicated to treat. The constraint they bring is like the Salesman problem. Every tenant wants to have the best next neighboor (with weight A/B = A wants B + B wants A). Unfortunately, this problem is NP-complete, meaning that you have to test most of combinatorics to find the optimal solution (O(!N)).

If N is very big, an heuristic solution may be used. You accept to have a good solution that might not be the best. For instance using a greedy algorithm: you first put together couple of neighboor with the best weight and so on.

EDIT: If you really want the optimal solution. It is the one maximizing the fitness function F (coming from the weights priority).

First, compute for every tenant **i**, the potential "hapiness" **Pi** he can have, which is the sum of

- the best house weight ,
- the two best neighboor weights.

Then use an heuristic to find a good solution F0. For instance a simple greedy algorithm. You take the tenants one by one and place them to the house that gives the most hapiness. If possible start with the tenants having more position priority and finish with the one having more neighboor priority.

Now you want to explore the tree of possibilities to improve Fmax which is F0 for the moment. But you cannot explore the full tree (!N possibilities). So you have to "prune" some branch. That means that everytime you place a tenant in a house, you compute the potential of this branch. For every tenant, you check which desire cannot be completed anymore and sum up the best remaining choices. if F <= Fmax, this branch has no interest, so do not explore it. If you finally reach the end of the branch and F > Fmax, you found a better solution, update Fmax.

NB: the better is your initial solution F0, the more branch you won't have to explore, the faster your code will run. A small improvement on F0 can change execution time of several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks Vince. I understand. Can I somehow "add" the neighbor priorities to the assignment problem? If not, do you know a way to solve both location and neighbors? I can neglect the amount of required priorities to simplify but I do want the combination of houses and neighbors.
There's identical number of houses and tenants (~20 so N is relatively small) so I don't care about complexity, it can run for hours if needed.

Comment: No you can't add neighboor constrain to the assignement problem. In fact you have to test complete solutions one by one. N=20 is small but !20 is tremendeous.
If you really want the optimal solution, I add an edit to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use constraint programming to solve this problem. Here is a simple MiniZinc-model (https://www.minizinc.org) for the case where there are identical number (=5) of houses and tenants:

```
% data
int: n = 5;
set of int: HOUSE = 1..n;
set of int: PEOPLE = 1..n;

array[PEOPLE, HOUSE] of 0..3: houseValue = array2d(PEOPLE, HOUSE, [
    0, 2, 3, 1, 0,
    0, 2, 3, 1, 0,
    0, 2, 3, 0, 1,
    0, 3, 2, 1, 0,
    0, 2, 1, 3, 0]);
array[PEOPLE, PEOPLE] of 0..3: neighbourValue = array2d(PEOPLE, PEOPLE, [
    0, 2, 3, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 3, 1, 2,
    2, 0, 0, 1, 3,
    0, 3, 2, 0, 1,
    1, 2, 3, 0, 0]);

% model
include "globals.mzn";

% decision variables - who lives in each house?
array[HOUSE] of var PEOPLE: tenant;

% constraint - exactly one person lives in each house
constraint alldifferent(tenant);

var int: objHouse = 
    sum(h in HOUSE where tenant[h] > 0)(houseValue[tenant[h], h]);
var int: objNeighbours = 
    sum(h in HOUSE where h > 1)(neighbourValue[tenant[h], tenant[h-1]]) + % left neighbour
    sum(h in HOUSE where h < n)(neighbourValue[tenant[h], tenant[h+1]]); % right neighbour

solve 
maximize objHouse + objNeighbours;

output ["obj = \(objHouse + objNeighbours)\n"] ++ ["objHouse = \(objHouse)\n"] ++ ["objNeighbours = \(objNeighbours)\n"] ++ ["tenant = \(tenant)"];
```

For larger instances a mixed integer programming model might show better performance.

This answer considers the case where all houses are located in a row and only the direct neighbours matter.

Comment: Many thanks Magnus! very helpful! Please explain about the inputs but mostly - the outputs:

**obj = 18**
**objHouse=6**
**objNeighbours=12**
**tenant=[5, 3, 2, 1, 4]**

**obj=20**
**objHouse=8**
**objNeighbours=12**
**tenant = [5, 4, 2, 1, 3]**

**obj=22**
**objHouse=6**
**objNeighbours=16**
**tenant=[2, 5, 3, 1, 4]**

**obj=24**
**objHouse=8**
**objNeighbours=16**
**tenant=[4, 1, 3, 5, 2]**

**obj=25**
**objHouse=10**
**objNeighbours=15**
**tenant=[1, 4, 2, 5, 3]**

How can I tell which house is chosen for each tenant? And which neighbors are selected?

Comment: The output is showing gradually improving solutions. The double line at the end shows the last solution is optimal. One elegant way to show which house is chosen for each tenant would be to introduce a new variable `array[PEOPLE] of var HOUSE: house;` and add a constraint channeling `house` to `tenant` like `constraint inverse(tenant, house);`. Finally append the new variable `house` to the output statement.

Comment: The input parameters `houseValue` and `neighbourValue` are my understanding of your data. Each person can once give 3, 2 and 1 value to houses and other people, the rest are 0. Here, if you want to use the same model for multiple data it would be a good idea to split the data and the model into separate files.